# Increasing, Decreasing, Monotonic....

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is this right? I'm trying to learn by following some examples in my lecture slides but really want to confirm with someone, preferably someone learned in math, so I thought of posting here. Cheers.

Q: Determine if the following sequence is increasing, decreasing, not monotonic, bounded below, bounded above and/or bounded
$$ \{\frac{2n^2-1}{n}\}^\infty_{n=2} $$

A: $$   a_n=\frac{2n^2-1}{n}      $$
$$  a_{n+1}=\frac{2(n+1)^2-1}{n+1}  $$
$$  a_{n+1}-a_n  $$
$$  \frac{2(n+1)^2-1}{n+1}-\frac{2n^2-1}{n}  $$
$$  \frac{2n^2+4n+2-1}{n+1}-\frac{2n^2-1}{n}  $$
$$  \frac{2n^2+4n+1}{n+1}-\frac{2n^2-1}{n}  $$
$$  \frac{2n^3+4n^2+n-2n^3-2n^2+n+1}{n^2+n}  $$
$$  \frac{2n^3+4n^2+n-2n^3-2n^2+n+1}{n^2+n}  $$
$$  \frac{2n^2+2n+1}{n^2+n}  $$
$$  \frac{2n^2}{n^2}  $$
$$ 2 $$
Strictly Increasing & Striclty monotonic

Comment: There's not a single word in your "answer"!

Comment: You have to add a backslash like this `\{` and `\}` in order for the curly braces to appear in math mode, see e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268768).

Comment: There should be equal signs connecting every line in your calculation of $a_{n + 1} - a_n$.  You are asserting that each line is equal to the previous line and, therefore, equal to $a_{n + 1} - a_n$.  However, the assertion $$\frac{2n^2 + 2n + 1}{n^2 + n}  = \frac{2n^2}{n^2}$$ is false.

Answer (score 1):

The one biggest flaw in your argument is that it contains only equations. Proofs should always *tell a story*, not just list equations. If you use an equation and you don't explain why you used it, the equation is useless.

That said, there are also calculation flaws, since I don't really see how you can get from $$\frac{2n^2+2n+1}{n^2+n}$$ to $$\frac{2n^2}{n^2}.$$

Comment: oh right sorry. I got carried away while solving and thought I was computing the limit. I've edited it.....is this now correct?

Answer (score 0):

Ok taking your responses into account I have come up with this:

A:

Testing the difference of successive terms,

Let  $$    a_n=\frac{2n^2-1}{n}      $$

So,
$$  a_{n+1}=\frac{2(n+1)^2-1}{n+1}  $$
$$  a_{n+1}-a_n  $$
$$  \frac{2(n+1)^2-1}{n+1}-\frac{2n^2-1}{n}  $$
$$  \frac{2n^2+4n+2-1}{n+1}-\frac{2n^2-1}{n}  $$
$$  \frac{2n^2+4n+1}{n+1}-\frac{2n^2-1}{n}  $$
$$  \frac{2n^3+4n^2+n-2n^3-2n^2+n+1}{n^2+n}  $$
$$  \frac{2n^3+4n^2+n-2n^3-2n^2+n+1}{n^2+n}  $$
$$  \frac{2n^2+2n+1}{n^2+n} > 0 $$
for all n >= 2

Thus, $ \{\frac{2n^2-1}{n}\}^\infty_{n=2} $ is Strictly Increasing & Strictly monotonic

Comment: Rather than posting an answer, you should edit your original question. And your answer could still benefit from a little more words in it. And some explanation why the final expression is greater than $0$.